# Refactoring a method that relies on a loop

Tags: java, list, for-loop, methods, refactoring

My java code below increments an `int` value depending on *how many dogs* in a `list` are over *a certain age*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dogList.size(); i++) {
    if (dogList.get(i).getAge() > 5) {
        dogsOverFive++
        continue;
    }           
}
```

What would be best practice for refactoring my code into its own method?
Should I pass `i` and the `list` as a parameter?

Comment: No you should just pass the `list` as a parameter Like `public void doSomething(ArrayList<....> .....) {}`

Comment: Yes but then it cannot get the int "i" that it needs to iterate through?

Comment: I'd say refactor by passing the `List` as parameter, and the desired threshold for dog age, into a `static` method. This way you can use it with any age.

Comment: @3kings might be a good idea to return the "dog-count" :) `public int doSomething ....`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
public static int olderThan(List<Dog> dogList, int age) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dogList.size(); i++) {
        if (dogList.get(i).getAge() > age) {
            count++;
            continue;
        }           
    }
    return count;
}
```

By the way `continue;` statement is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass a `list` and an `age` as parameters and return an amount of such dogs as an `int` value.

I suggest considering my Java 8 solution.

```
public int olderThan(List<Dog> list, int age) {
    return (int)list.stream().filter(dog -> dog.getAge() > age).count();
}
```

Other standard ways have been shown by my colleagues @Nikolas Charalambidis and @Dmitry Bychenko.